# Generating random number with bounds produces unexpected output in Bash

Tags: bash, random

I am trying to learn bash so I was working on a "guess the number" type game.  I am at the point of trying to generate random numbers based on the user's input for lower and upper bounds.  But some test cases seem to create numbers that don't make sense; some being outside my bounds and others not being what I would expect.

Here is my program

```
echo "Enter the lower bound: "
echo -n "> "
read lowerBound

while [ "$lowerBound" -lt 0 ]
do
    echo "Lower bound must be >= 0.  Please try again: "
    echo -n "> "
    read lowerBound
done

echo
echo "Enter the upper bound: "
echo -n "> "
read upperBound

lowerLimit=$(($lowerBound + 1))

while [ "$upperBound" -lt "$lowerLimit" ]
do
    echo "Upper bound must be larger than lower bound. Please try again: "
    echo -n "> "
    read upperBound
done

echo
randNum=$(( $RANDOM % ( ($upperBound - $lowerBound) + 1 ) ))
echo "RANDOM=$RANDOM randNum=$randNum"
```

Here is an output that produced unexpected results.  I would expect 6: (9237 % (10-1+1) = 7 but output is 5)

```
Enter the lower bound:
> 1

Enter the upper bound:
> 10

RANDOM=9237 randNum=5
```

Finally here is some output where the generated number lies outside my bounds.  I understand this from doing the math myself, but thought this equation was supposed to generate random numbers in a range.  Here 26921 % (126-123+1) = 9237.  Most likely just a coincidence that 9237 appeared in subsequent runs.

```
Enter the lower bound:
> 123

Enter the upper bound:
> 126

RANDOM=26921 randNum=0
```

I'm not sure if my equation is wrong or if it is something I am doing wrong in Bash.  Any pointers would be appreciated.

Note: I am not new to programming, just new to Bash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each reference of `$RANDOM` generates a new number.

You can see this with something as simple as:

```
$ echo "$RANDOM : $RANDOM : $RANDOM"
297 : 20330 : 14461
```

In your code you get one `$RANDOM` value when you calculate `randNum`, and a second (and likely *different*) `$RANDOM` value in the `echo`; net result is `randNum=5` was not generated based on `$RANDOM=9237`.

If you want to reference the same `$RANDOM` value more than once you should first store it in a variable and then (re)use said variable as needed, eg:

```
ranx=$RANDOM
randNum=$(( $ranx % ( ($upperBound - $lowerBound) + 1 ) ))
echo "RANDOM=$ranx randNum=$randNum"
```

Comment: You're a lifesaver.  I was completely unaware and (mindlessly) treating $RANDOM like a variable when I should, and correct me if I'm wrong, be treating $RANDOM like a function call that returns a random integer. Thank you.